# Win32: Reporting technology that doesn't have to be installed or shipped

Tags: delphi, reporting

i'm looking for a reporting engine to replace Delphi 5's QuickReports.

Requirements

- free (*i'm not paying to find out if it works*)
- open source (*documentation is always lacking*)
- does not have to be registered on the client computer (no COM) (*single executable depoyment*)
- does not ship as a seaparate file (no dll) (*single executable deployment*)

Some things i've looked at:

- mshtml
- crystal
- nevrona rave

Comment: Crystal & Rave aren't free, both are commercial products. Having said that, a special edition of Rave is shipped with Delphi these days but not Delphi 5. Crystal definitely requires loads of DLLs to be installed (we deploy it with our software). We also use ReportBuilder which fits all of your requirements except "free".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try [free-report](http://www.fast-report.com/en/products/free-report-generator-for-delphi.html),

FreeReport 2.3 consists of a report engine, a designer, and a previewer. Its capabilities are comparable to QuickReport3 and ReportBuilder 3.52.
FreeReport 2.3 works with Delphi 2/3/4/5/6/7/2005 and 2006 and C++ Builder 1/3/4/2005/2006.
Freeware; royalty-free full source code.

donwload from [here](http://www.fast-report.com/en/download/free-report-download.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [brothersoft.com](http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/f/freereport-138801-1.jpeg))</sub>

[image]

Comment: Two people makes a consensus for FreeReport/FastReports (two sides of the same coin).

Comment: FastReport/FreeReport is a great product. It's capabilities are endless using it's own script language.
FR compile with your exe so nothing else to ship. Designer can be included so your reports can be editable, or new reports can be created later by the user.
I've used Crystal Report + VB in the past and deployment was a real nigthmare!

Answer (score 2):

If free means free to you, then you might want to look at the open source project [Report Manager](http://reportman.sourceforge.net/).

If free means free to distribute your work, then you should look at [FastReports](http://www.fast-report.com/en/support/).  It's the advanced version of FreeReport mentioned previously.  FastReports is incredibly flexible.  It's lightweight and completely compiled into your program.  It incorporates a scripting language.  It is all Delphi code.  The report files it creates are fairly readable XML files.  It can export the results in a number of formats.